# Using style from another assembly in Windows 10 aplication

Tags: xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a Universal Windows Class Library from Windows 10, where I implement some custom controls and themes. Now I put there a ResourceDictionary of Colors.

In WinRT to implement this ResourceDictionary to our main project is something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///GeekyTheory/Colors.xaml"/>
```

Where GeekyTheory is the namespace of my assembly. [Here is the open source project in question](https://github.com/GeekyTheory/GeekyTheory.Toolkit/blob/master/GeekyTheory%20(UWP)/Styles/Colors.xaml).

But how we can handle this in Windows 10?

Thank's!

Comment: have you tried `<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyExternalAssembly;path/Colors.xaml" /></Application.Resources>` ?

Comment: David Leitner, nope. This is the WPF expression. Maybe I'm loosing some concept... Is necessary to copy the resource xaml file into the Debug folder?

Comment: Have you ever resolved this? I am running into the same problem.

Comment: Nope, not yet. It was not urgent for me, but I will think about it how to do it. If some else know it, we will appreciate it!! :)